# Sum of 2 variable in BPEL?

Tags: bpel

i enter 2 variable (integer) in BPEL. I want to receive result is sum of them. Plz help me. (Using function available in BPEL). I think that it use Assign with Expression in Property. I don't know code to enter in Expression.

Answer (score 1):

BPEL uses XPath as expression language, so you can just use an ordinary XPath expression in your assign. If for instance you have the following variables:

```
<variables>
    <variable name="var1" type="xsd:int"/>
    <variable name="var2" type="xsd:int"/>
    <variable name="result" type="xsd:int"/>
</variables>
```

You can add `var1` and `var2` and store it in `result`:

```
        <assign>
            <copy>
                <from>$var1 + $var2</from>
                <to variable="result"/>
            </copy>
        </assign>
```